# EasyMock expect of void method with null argument passes eventhough actual call has not null argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have a method i want to test similar to this:

```
public void testedMethod() {
     mockedObject.doSomething(notNullValue, notNullValue);
}
```

I have a test method which uses an easymock mock for mockedObject and writes the following expectation:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
   mockedObject.doSomething(null, null);
   replay();

   testObject.testedMethod();
}
```

I thought this test would fail because my expectation has null argument while my real call has not-null arguments. I expected an assertion error with follwing message:

> Unexpected method call mockedObject.doSomething(NotNullValue@sljmf,
>   NotNullValue@djdlfjf)

I was wondering, is this a bug in EasyMock? or this intended behaviour?

Comment: Are you calling `replay(mockedObject)` and `verify(mockedObject)`?

Comment: There are many assumptions we could make about what is happening because you haven't provided a great amount of detail. What error are you seeing? Or are you seeing no error at all? How have you set the mockObject on the testObject? Are you sure the mockedObject is in record mode when you call the expectation? You've used replay(), but not replay(mockedObject), did you mean that? Why haven't you used verify() somewhere?

Comment: I'm using unitils framework, I create the mock object by annotating it with @Mock and use the EasyMockUnitils.replay method which automatically does the replay for all mock objects. The verify is also automatically done by unitils.

Comment: In mean time discovered the problem, it lies with the @Mock of unitils. It has as default setting to not use strict mode of the mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mockedObject was not created as a strict-mock.